# Protocol Specification of Metro TRK or App TRK

Tags: symbian, metrowerks, apptrk

Can somebody point to the protocol docs of Metro TRK and/or App TRK that is used for on device debugging for Symbian Application?

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful:

http://cache.freescale.com/files/soft_dev_tools/doc/ref_manual/METROTRKRM.pdf

Chapter "3 - MetroTRK Communications" on page 23 is about:

"Describes the MetroTRK communication protocol. This chapter is useful for debugging MetroTRK and for those developing software that communicates with MetroTRK."

Comment: Thanks - Overall seems pretty useful, but this is the general Metro TRK. Have you come across any doc related to symbian specific implementation?